# using Unicode 'dingbat-like' glyphs in R graphics, across devices & platforms, especially PDF

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, unicode

Some of you may have seen my [blog post](http://bmb-common.blogspot.com/2011/05/unicode-symbols-in-r.html) on this topic, where I wrote the following code after wanting to help a friend produce half-filled circles as points on a graph:

```
TestUnicode <- function(start="25a0", end="25ff", ...)
  {
    nstart <- as.hexmode(start)
    nend <- as.hexmode(end)
    r <- nstart:nend
    s <- ceiling(sqrt(length(r)))
    par(pty="s")
    plot(c(-1,(s)), c(-1,(s)), type="n", xlab="", ylab="",
         xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
    grid(s+1, s+1, lty=1)
    for(i in seq(r)) {
      try(points(i%%s, i%/%s, pch=-1*r[i],...))
    }
  }

TestUnicode(9500,9900)
```

This works (i.e. produces a nearly-full grid of cool dingbatty symbols):

- on Ubuntu 10.04, in an X11 or PNG device
- on Mandriva Linux distribution, same devices, with locally built R, once pango-devel was installed

It fails to varying degrees (i.e. produces a grid partly or entirely filled with dots or empty rectangles), either silently or with warnings:

- on the same Ubuntu 10.04 machine in PDF or PostScript (tried setting font="NimbusSan" to use URW fonts, doesn't help)
- on MacOS X.6 (quartz, X11, Cairo, PDF)

For example, trying all the available PDF font families:

```
flist <- c("AvantGarde", "Bookman","Courier", "Helvetica", "Helvetica-Narrow",
        "NewCenturySchoolbook", "Palatino", "Times","URWGothic",
        "URWBookman", "NimbusMon", "NimbusSan", "NimbusSanCond",
        "CenturySch", "URWPalladio","NimbusRom")

for (f in flist) {
  fn <- paste("utest_",f,".pdf",sep="")
  pdf(fn,family=f)
  TestUnicode()
  title(main=f)
  dev.off()
  embedFonts(fn)
}
```

on Ubuntu, none of these files contains the symbols.

It would be nice to get it to work on as many combinations as possible, but especially in some vector format and double-especially in PDF.

Any suggestions about font/graphics device configurations that would make this work would be welcomed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are out of luck Ben, as, according to some notes by Paul Murrell, `pdf()` can only handle single-byte encodings. Multi-byte encodings need to be converted to a the single-byte equivalent, and therein lies the rub; by definition, single-byte encodings cannot contain all the glyphs that can be represented in a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8, say.

Paul's notes can be found [here](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/PDF/pdfEncoding.html) wherein he suggests a couple of solutions using Cairo-based PDF devices, using `cairo_pdf()` on suitably-endowed Linux and Mac OS systems, or via the `Cairo` package under MS Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I have found the `cairo_pdf` device to be completely insufficient: the output is markedly different from both `pdf` and on-screen rendering, and its plotmath support is sketchy.

However, there’s a rather simple workaround on OS X: Use the “normal” `quartz` device and set its `type` to `pdf`:

```
quartz(type = 'pdf', file = 'output.pdf')
```

Unfortunately, on my computer this ignores the font family and always uses Helvetica (although the documentation claims that the default is Arial).

There are at least two other gotchas:

- [`pdf` converts hyphens to minuses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14780860/1968). This may not even always be what you want but it’s quite useful to properly typeset negative numbers. The linked thread describes workarounds for this.
- It’s of course platform specific and only works on OS X.

(I realise that OP briefly mentions the Quartz device but this thread is frequently viewed and I think this solution needs more prominence.)

Comment: can you be more specific/give specific examples of the problems, especially those with plotmath rendering?  It would probably help to give the results of `sessionInfo()` too ...

Comment: @Ben Hmm, since this post isn’t really about plotmath, maybe a comment suffices. Tell me if you feel otherwise. Here goes: Cairo only implements a subset of plotmath; it doesn’t implement some of the symbols (see `demo(plotmath)`), some of the spaces are off, and it doesn’t support italic text (with Helvetica at least). [R v3.0.1, x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 in case that’s relevant, but I doubt it]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution might be to use [tikzDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/) which can now use XeLaTeX with Unicode characters. The resulting tex file can then be compiled to produce a pdf. The problem is still that you must have a font on your system that contains the characters.

```
library(tikzDevice)
options(tikzXelatexPackages=c(getOption('tikzXelatexPackages'),
    '\\setromanfont{Courier New}'))
tikz(engine='xetex',standAlone=T)
TestUnicode(9500,9900)
dev.off()
```

*The first time, this will take a LONG time.*

Comment: Hmmm.  Tip appreciated.  I installed XeTeX (on Ubuntu, `apt-get install texlive-xetex`), but I don't seem to have "Courier New" on my (Ubuntu 10.04) system (or at least XeTeX can't find it: normally `apt-get install` runs all of the TeX updates necessary ...). Suggestions for how to guess/find an appropriate font?

Comment: `fc-list | grep -i ding` should show a list of fonts installed on your computer that contain the word "ding" in their names. XeTeX should be able to access these using `fontspec` commands.

Comment: `Courier New` was just an arbitrary choice, as Sharpie mentioned, you will need to find a font on your system that has the symbols.

Comment: Double hmmm.  I pursued this a little way because it seems like a nice alternative, and might work on some systems where the cairo_pdf() solution does not, but ... all I know in my current state of cluelessness is that `cairo_pdf` seems to find a suitable font automatically (at least on Mandriva or Ubuntu systems with pango installed), whereas it would take me a while to dig through and figure out how to find the appropriate fonts, translate the names to their XeTeX equivalents, etc..

Comment: (Was running out of room in the previous comment.) The `fc-list` command given above returns `Dingbats:style=Regular` on my system.  I'm not sure I know how to translate this to a valid XeTeX font specification ... naively changing `Courier New` to `Dingbats` in the code above fails.  Bottom line: this seems interesting, but (given that I have a solution that works for me) probably not worth my effort pursuing at this point.  Hopefully it will be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *embedding* a font in the PDF, or including one for Mac users that would work?

Comment: Thanks.  Can you be slightly more specific? R has an `embedFonts()` function, but I believe that's intended to post-process a PDF/PostScript to make sure that fonts that are present on the current system get embedded in the file. This is (I think) a different situation, where the fonts used by R for the pdf don't include the glyphs in the first place.  For example, `pdf("test.pdf", family="NimbusSan"); TestUnicode(); dev.off()` fails.