# How do I write a plot containing a symbol to PDF in R?

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, plotmath

I want to use the infinity sign on the  x-axis of a box plot in R, which I want to write to a PDF file.

I can set the infinity symbol by doing

```
names(data)[9] <- "∞"
```

but that gets me encoding errors when trying to write:

```
conversion failure on '∞' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <...>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use Unicode as in this example: [using Unicode 'dingbat-like' glyphs in R graphics, across devices & platforms, especially PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-es) (infinity is Unicode 8734): in particular, it's possible that simply using a `cairoPDF` device will make this work. Probably a better idea is to use `?plotmath` capabilities (as referenced in `?boxplot` under the `names` argument:

```
 boxplot(matrix(1:10,ncol=2),names=c("a",expression(infinity)))
```

Comment: Hmpf, I tried setting `expression(infinity)` the way I set the symbol in the question and that failed. Your version works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure how you're trying to place the label, but the following code works for me:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10

pdf("infty.pdf")
plot(x,y,xlab=expression(infinity))
dev.off()
```

in that it produces a PDF with the x axis labelled with an infinity symbol. For mathematical symbols, I would recommend not trying to store them as characters and expecting R to treat them like it does other characters. See `?plotmath` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on MacOS with the symbols for male (mars unicode \u2642) and female(venus unicode \u2640). pdf() would not plot them, replacing them by dots.

I then installed Cairo and at first that did not work either (instead it replaced the symbols with rectangles) until I typed

cairo_pdf(pdf.file,family="Arial Unicode MS")

which works. The problem is to find a font with the symbol you want defined, so there is no guarantee that it will work for other symbols.