# R and unicode PDF fonts on linux - letters got stuck together

Tags: r, pdf, unicode, utf-8, fonts

I have a little problem in Unicode PDF/postscript fonts in R on linux, using Czech UTF glyphs.

It's quite simple - I have something - for example, the word `Měsíce` - written on R plot, which is painted to PDF device, with the default font `Helvetica`.

The PDF is painted correctly, but if I open/print the file on Windows in Adobe Reader, it looks (and, sandly, prints) like this:

[image: Mesice]

Interesting thing is - if I open the same PDF in Mac OS X in Preview.app, the letters seem correct (I cannot test it on Linux PDF viewer right now). Also, if I *create* the file on Mac version of R, it looks good on all systems, too. However, I *have* to create the PDF file on the Linux machine, so I want to make it work.

Also, if I try to change the font in R by setting `family="some other font"`, in most fonts the Czech glyphs are not even present at all. The only other font than `Helvetica` that has the Czech glyphs is `Times`, but it "mangles" the letters in simmilar way.

I use Debian 6.0.1 (squeeze), R version is 2.11.1, installed by `apt-get`. I use the default R PDF device.

Comment: Yes -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-es is relevant (although not identical)

Comment: Care to make the title a bit more informative to help search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it was easy.

I had to use `cairo_pdf()` instead of the default PDF device. That did the trick.