# export ggplot figures containing special symbol in R?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, export

I generated a figure using ggplot in R and I want to save it as pdf. My problem is that my figure when exported (using ggsave or pdf function) into pdf does not contain the symbol **≥ 8** in the legend. Instead I see **...8**.
In addition I get a warning message:
`In grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  conversion failure on '≥ 8' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e2>`

Does anybody know a way to correct that issue?
Thanks

Comment: The [`cairo` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/Cairo.pdf) can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting symbols fails in PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096152/plotting-symbols-fails-in-pdf)

Comment: I am having the same issue  when calling  cairo_pdf. I would be good to have a definite fix.