# corrupted UTF characters in pdf plots generated by R

Tags: r, pdf, utf

I am trying to save plots with legends containing UTF characters for Males and Females to pdf in `R`. When I plot to graphics device :

```
plot(1)
legend('topright', bty = 'n', 
       expression(italic("legend"~"\u2640"~"\u2642")))
```

the legend of plot looks as expected

[image]

I can even save it to pdf by right click and "save to pdf". However, when I use inbuilt function `pdf`

```
pdf('test.pdf')
plot(1)
legend('topright', bty = 'n',
       expression(italic("legend"~"\u2640"~"\u2642")))
dev.off()
```

it drops a warning and shows corrupted characters instead:

[image]

`cairo_pdf` does not drop a warning, but it does not show the correct symbols either:

[image]

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096152/plotting-symbols-fails-in-pdf), I should specify encoding that would support my symbols, however I have no idea how to find out which it does (besides default `Helvetica` I tried `MacRoman` without success).

It is apparent that it is possible for R to generate pdf that contains these symbols (because I am able to do so by the right click). However, I would like to achieve that in automatized manner.

My R session settings:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

I also managed to reproduce same behaviour on another computer with macOS Sierra 10.12.1.

Comment: The reason why I am hesitant to delete this question is that it took me 4 hours to find correct answer in question with accepted answer that did not worked for me. Maybe having it will simplify search for other people, I leave this decision on community.

Answer (score 3):

A working answer on **OS X** is using `quartz`:

```
quartz(type = 'pdf', file = 'test.pdf')
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19610909/2962344

`cairo_pdf` seems to work on **Linux**.

Comment: Did you try `CairoPDF` from `Cairo` library? It's not the same as `cairo_pdf()` function.

Answer (score 1):

hi this is working for me (on windows)

```
cairo_pdf('test.pdf' , family="DejaVu Sans")
plot(1)
legend('topright', bty = 'n',
  paste("legend",quote("\u2640")  ,quote("\u2642")  )) 
dev.off()
```

[Unicode Characters in ggplot2 PDF Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768176/unicode-characters-in-ggplot2-pdf-output)

on mac try this

```
pdf('test.pdf',encoding="MacRoman")
```

[Plotting symbols fails in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096152/plotting-symbols-fails-in-pdf)

Comment: Neither `cairo_pdf('test.pdf' , family="DejaVu Sans")` nor `pdf('test.pdf',encoding="MacRoman")` works. It produces exactly same outputs as without specification of encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the other solutions did not work for me, and finally I used png instead of pdf:

```
png('test.png', units="in", width=11, height=10, res = 600)
plot(1)
legend('topright', bty = 'n',
       expression(italic("legend"~"\u2640"~"\u2642")))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux `ggsave` with `expression(mu)` works

```
draw_label(expression(paste("50 ", mu, " m")))

ggsave(...)
```