# ggsave losing unicode characters from ggplot+gridExtra

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2

More code than you really need, but to set the mood:

```
#Make some data and load packages
data<-data.frame(pchange=runif(80,0,1),group=factor(sample(c(1,2,3),80,replace=T)))
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
data%<>%arrange(group,pchange) %>% mutate(num=1:80)

#Make plot that includes unicode characters
g1<-ggplot(data, aes(factor(num),pchange, fill = group,width=.4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position="right")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,.25,.5,.75,1))+
  xlab("")+
  scale_fill_discrete("Arbitrary Group",
                      breaks=c(1,2,3),
                      labels=c("< 1 Year", "\u2265 1 Year & \n\u2264 5 Years","> 5 Years"))


#I want to add an A below the plot (this may not be necessary for the issue, but its a part of the workflow so I thought I'd include it.
g <- arrangeGrob(plot=g1,
                 sub = textGrob("A",
                                x = .1,
                                hjust = .5,
                                vjust=-2,
                                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold",
                                          fontsize = 16,
                                          col="black")))

#Save the plot
ggsave(filename="X:/yourpath/Plot1.pdf", plot=g,
       width = 8, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Actual Plot]

Here's what it should look like (in terms of the characters in the key; plot taken as jpeg directly from Rstudio plot window):
[image: Ideal Plot]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two options. One, use the `cairo_pdf` device instead of the default `pdf` in your call you `ggsave`, e.g.,

```
library(Cairo)
ggsave(filename="X:/yourpath/Plot1.pdf", plot=g, device=cairo_pdf,
       width = 8, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

The other option would be to use expressions instead of explicit unicode characters:

```
g<-ggplot(data, aes(factor(num),pchange, fill = group,width=.4)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position="right")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,.25,.5,.75,1))+
  xlab("")+
  scale_fill_discrete("Arbitrary Group",
                      breaks=c(1,2,3),
                      labels=c(expression(phantom(0) < "1 Year"), 
                              expression(paste(phantom(0) >= "1 Year &", phantom(0) <= "5 Years")),
                              expression(phantom(0) > "5 Years")))



ggsave(filename="Plot1.pdf", plot=g,
       width = 8, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

Although, as you can see, with the second option the formatting isn't as tight as you might like.

As to why you are experiencing this issue, according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e/5886296#5886296), the `pdf` driver can only handle single byte encodings.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to `ggsave()` to work with `device=cairo_pdf`. I get the error: `Error in grid.newpage() : 
  cairo error 'error while writing to output stream'` Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try it with `CairoPDF` from the **Cairo** package?

Comment: 1) Either. I was getting the error with the g or g1 object. 2) Also, from a [quick](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-cairographics-with-ggsave/) search, it seems that Cairo is producing bitmap instead of vector output. If that is true, it is preferred that I stay in vector format. Thus, I will use `expressions`, though I can't figure out a good way to pull the second label to two lines as I had before.

Comment: any pdf is a vector format. I think you're misunderstanding that post.

Comment: `device=cairo_pdf` solved this problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde from `?cairo_pdf`: "Note that unlike postscript and pdf, cairo_pdf and cairo_ps sometimes record bitmaps and not vector graphics. On the other hand, they can (on suitable platforms) include a much wider range of UTF-8 glyphs, and embed the fonts used." (sorry for necroing this ;) )