# Cannot embed ggplot2 (/R) fonts in PDF with ggsave()

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I have added a font to my ggplot2-plot, and it works perfectly when viewed in RStudio's plot viewer. However, when I try to save the plot as a PDF, NO text at all is printed (see code and pictures below):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)) # Dummy data 

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + # Dummy plot
   geom_point() +
   labs(title = "Correct font in R, NO fonts at all in pdf :-(") +
   theme(text = element_text(family = "latex"))
```

Then I try to ggsave() the plot with the following code:

```
 ggsave("df_plot.pdf", 
   plot = plot, 
   device = "pdf", 
   dpi = 320)
```

But I get an error message:

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x,
>   x$y,  :    invalid font type

Below is the plot with the correct fonts (in RStudio) + the plot that is written to my pdf file (with no fonts at all):

[Plot with correct font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2inF.png)
[Plot witn NO text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH4pL.png)

What am I missing here? I've tried various stuff with the extrafont package, but the pdfs don't print the fonts there either (if something *is* printed, its just the default fonts).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746938/ggsave-losing-unicode-characters-from-ggplotgridextra/28747843#28747843

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `ggsave()` appears to work fine for me. The error is actually adding the `theme(text = element_text(family = "latex"))` to the plot.

Adjusting the example a little bit,

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)) # Dummy data 

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + # Dummy plot
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Correct font in R, NO fonts at all in pdf :-(")  

ggsave("df_plot.pdf", 
       plot = plot, 
       device = "pdf", 
       dpi = 320)
#Saving 10.7 x 8.01 in image
```

But,

```
plot +  theme(text         = element_text(size=10, family="LM Roman 10"))
```

produces the error you've found:

> Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
>     polygon edge not found.

This question has already been answered here: 
[Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : Polygon edge not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581440/error-in-grid-calll-textbounds-as-graphicsannotxlabel-xx-xy-polygon)

Do these suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you may consider using the [`extrafont`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-custom-fonts-to-ggplot-in-r/) package:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(extrafont)
fonts()
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10)) # Dummy data 
windowsFonts(Calibri = windowsFont("Calibri"))
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + # Dummy plot
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Correct font in R, NO fonts at all in pdf :-(") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15, family= "Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold"))



ggsave("df_plot.pdf", 
       plot = plot, 
       device = cairo_pdf, 
       dpi = 320)
```

[image]