# Encoding KNIME R-Snippet in pdf export (Special Characters)

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, knime

I have a Encoding Problem in KNIME.

Following code works perfectly in RStudio, the symbol ° is printed out correctly.

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

fn <- "C:/Temp/textR.pdf"
pdf(file=fn)
df <- data.frame("crit °C", 1)
g1 <- tableGrob(format(df, core.just="left"))
grid.arrange(g1,  ncol = 1)
dev.off()
```

I want to use this code in an R Snippet in KNIME, unfortunately it won´t work there, instead of "°" I get "Â°".

What i already tried:

- setting Preferences to UTF-8 in KNIME ->Preferences->General->Workspace
- https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-textprocessing/problems-exporting-utf-8-csv-writer
- use ggsave
- use Pdf Cairo instead (solution from [using Unicode 'dingbat-like' glyphs in R graphics, across devices & platforms, especially PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e)) but i am not sure if I had the family package installed...

Can anyone help me? I am using  KNIME 3.1.1 and R_3_2_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working well for me (also Windows, in my case Windows 10, 64 bit, English locale, KNIME 3.1.2, R 3.0.3).

You might give a try with the following change:

```
df <- data.frame("crit \u00B0C", 1)
```

(`\u00B0` stands for the unicode degree sign.)

Comment: THANKS! nice workaround, for variables u can achieve by just replacing the character:        unit_symbol <- gsub("°", "\u00B0", unit_symbol)