# How do I save special unicode characters in PDF?

Tags: r

I want to create plots with special characters. A simplified version of the problem I'm facing is shown in the code below. I expect the code to output an eight-spoked asterisk, but instead I get ... in the output.

I have tried the `cairo_pdf` solution which is commonly referred to on the internet. Also, I appreciate any information that can help me improve my general knowledge of Unicode systems and graphic devices in `R` in relation to this problem.

```
pdf("out.pdf")
grid::grid.text("\U2733")
dev.off()
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e - note the answers are likely to be somewhat platform-dependent.